# Maven add a repository for a specific OS

Tags: maven, repository

I am new to maven and I am trying to create a single pom file for both linux and windows. For dependency resolution, I have 2 p2 repositories. 1 for windows and the other is for linux.
I also have a target definition (.target) in which I am adding all external repositories for dependecy resolution.
Is there a way that I can add/activate a repository location per OS? Below is my trial.

Using maven pom profiles:
In this trial, I added all my repositories (common for windows and linux) to the target definition. I then created 2 new profiles and added the OS-specific p2 repo like so

```
<profile>
  <id>Linux</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    <os><name>linux</name></os>
  </activation>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>p2_lin</id>
    <url>http://example.com/data/LINUX_P2</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>Windows</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    <os><name>win32</name></os>
  </activation>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>trace_p2_win</id>
    <url>http://example.com/data/WINDOWS_P2</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
</profile>
```

While calling maven, I add this profile to the parameters `mvn clean install -PWindows,Test`

Unfortunately, the above configuration gives an unsatisfied dependency.
But when I remove this section from the parent pom file and add the correct repository (example: >http://example.com/data/WINDOWS_P2) to the target definition without the other one, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Could you please share what .target definition means? Never heard about it in maven and I haven't found it in official documentation.

Comment: Before attempting to solve the issue: since you explicitly specify profile name, why do you also use an os-name-based activation?